# Ramanujan conjecture and Langlands program

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In the article  http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/the-legacy-of-srinivasa-ramanujan/article2746988.ece, it was mentioned that

"This conjecture, later called Ramanujan's conjecture, came to play a pivotal role in the towering edifice known as the Langlands program, a far-reaching program articulated by R.P. Langlands in the 1970s."

How does Ramanujan conjecture play a role in the development of the Langlands program?

Ramanujan Conjecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan-Petersson_conjecture

Comment: This is answered in the section "Ramanujan–Petersson conjecture for automorphic forms" of the second link.

Comment: See also chapter 11 of "Number Theory 3 : Iwasawa Theory and Modular Forms", by Kurokawa-Kurihara-Saito